# How can I detect whether the Internet is actively being used by other people automatically

Tags: networking, automation

I have a task that consumes a large amount of Internet bandwidth. Normally I'd just setup QoS settings in my router, but my current router doesn't have that feature and it cannot be replaced. As such, I'd like to control when the bandwidth heavy task runs to not effect normal usage.

There's three potential users of the Internet, 2 with android phones and one with an iPhone. All the devices seem to respond to pings so I could setup a script to monitor if the devices are present at the household. However, I read somewhere that modern smartphones may turn off the wifi in periods of inactivity, and we have fixed devices that access the Internet as well (Samsung smart TVs) that may be the only thing accessing the Internet. Also, even if pings worked 100% of the time there'd be a large period of time when everyone is sleeping that the task could run.

Our schedules are random, so setting up a timed schedule doesn't work.

I'd like to do this as unintrusively as possible, IE no installation of apps on phones and no adding hardware to rooms that could be perceived as "ugly", but I'm stumped how to do it aside from switching the task on and off manually. I don't mind programming my own scripts but I don't know what I could use as input.

Our Cogeco router does have "motion sensors" to detect presence, but there doesn't seem to be an API for that.

Comment: You could try to analyze the WiFi traffic, but you might need to find a WiFi adapter that has a working promiscuous mode. It would be much easier to disable WiFi on your first router and add a second router that supports QoS or any other features you need. (Of course this does add hardware.)

Answer (score 0):

> However, I read somewhere that modern smartphones may turn off the wifi in periods of inactivity

Well, if they're in a period of inactivity, then it literally means *internet is not being actively used* by the smartphone's owner right now, and therefore you can treat it just like "person is not present".

> Normally I'd just setup QoS settings in my router,

You can still set up traffic shaping on the machine that runs the task, limiting it to e.g. 80% of the total capacity of your WAN connection.

When downloading data, high bandwidth usage should not, generally, have a significant negative effect on ordinary web browsing or e.g. video streaming. If it does, something else is going wrong beyond just "large bandwidth consumption".

(For TCP on Linux, maybe set the connection to use the TCP-LP congestion control algorithm – it should have less of an effect on other users – but even the defaults should normally behave "fairly".)

If you're *uploading* a lot of data – throttle it to 80% of your available upload to work around lack of QoS (leaving some space for TCP ACKs and such).

> How can I detect whether the Internet is actively being used by other people automatically

Two approaches come to mind:

1. Your home router probably supports UPnP IGD for automatic port-forwarding by apps. This protocol also includes WAN monitoring – `upnpc -l` or `upnpc -L` will show you the current "bytes sent/received", and if you take two measurements one second apart you'll have an approximate "MB/s" utilization and you'll be able to see whether someone's in a video call or something.
2. Many home Internet connections are heavily affected by Bufferbloat, and heavy usage causes latency to increase massively (which is probably why your high-bandwidth task has such a negative effect on other users, too). You can actually probably use this to your advantage and *monitor* the latency to some host that you know is nearby (maybe a DNS server hosted at the same ISP) – if the latency jumps, it means someone's using the network heavily.

   This method doesn't help you detect light but latency-sensitive traffic such as games, but it might at least detect large uploads/downloads.

Comment: The heavy traffic is TCP and UDP tunneled via an UDP VPN. When it's running it causes movie/TV streaming to buffer frequently or not work at all. What's strange is that at its highest speed (~5Mbyte/s) isn't really close to our supposed top speed of 1Gbit (~500Mbit during testing with fast.com)

Comment: @KaidenPrince  Is the 500mbit your upload speed?  Many ISP provide 500Mbit and more download speed, but then only give you 20-40mbit upload speed.

Comment: My Internet speed seems to be variable. Hard capped at 1gbps/100Mbps, but will frequently be less evenings and weekends (when school is out)